# FastAPI: Access Redis Cache Inside of Pydantic Validator

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, pydantic

I'm aware that it is typically not recommended to perform any IO operations inside of a Pydantic validator (see https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/979). However, what is not clear to me is if asyncio operations are OK to perform inside of the validator.

For example, if I have a validator that calls `await redis.get()` is that going to have a significant negative performance hit?

Comment: I don't think you can have async validator https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/857  the performance hit usually goes the other way, if you call a slow synchronous method from your async code

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware that you can't use async validators. Looks like I will need to come up with another way to validate from the cache then.